# detect when a child component is clicked outside

Tags: angular

I have a child component called: `mycomponent` with this code:

```
import { Component,Input } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "mycomponent",
  templateUrl: "./mycomponent.html"
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() myArray: any;
  @Input() index: any;
  @Input() indexSelected: any;
  constructor() {
  }
}
<input type="text" (click)="bShow=true" >{{myArray}}
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:200px; height:50px;" *ngIf="indexSelected==index">
  data: {{myArray}}
  <br>
  <button (click)="indexSelected=null">close</button>
</div>
```

I am calling it in app.ts:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of myArray">
  <mycomponent [myArray]="item"></mycomponent>
  <br>
</ng-container>
```

in app.ts

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of myArray; let i=index" >
  <mycomponent (click)="fn_selectIndex(i)" [myArray]="item" [indexSelected]="indexSelected"  [index]="i"></mycomponent>
<br>
</ng-container>

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myArray:any=[1,2,3,4,5];
  indexSelected=null;

fn_selectIndex(i:any){ 
  this.indexSelected=i;
}
}
```

when I click on the `input` of `mycomponent` a `div` is displayed.

How can I make the `div` disappear when I click outside of it, except when I click on the same `input`?

[image]

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atr1zm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmycomponent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stopPropagation` event

app.html

```
<div (click)="fn_selectIndex($event, -1)" style="height:100vh">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of myArray; let i=index" >
    <mycomponent (click)="fn_selectIndex($event, i)" [myArray]="item" [indexSelected]="indexSelected"  [index]="i"></mycomponent>
  <br>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

app.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  myArray:any=[1,2,3,4,5];
  indexSelected=null;s

 fn_selectIndex(event, i:any){
   this.indexSelected=i;
   event.stopPropagation();
 }
}
```

Reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edld9f?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Consider listening on `focus` and `blur` events
[I have changed your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ss2pxu?file=src/app/mycomponent.ts)

[anthor idea](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-exvw4i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thanks genius! but I have this problem: https://imgur.com/xmGNt3o the idea is that you can click on the content of the div and it won't close unless you click outside

Comment: Give another idea for you! It's up to you to perfect the code